# Difference between gets() and scanf("%s")

Tags: c, pointers, buffer, dynamic-memory-allocation

I declared a character pointer, and used it for to scan a string in runtime; I don't know the number of characters that I'm going to enter, so I didn't use `calloc` or `malloc`. The program ends when it reached the line `scanf("%s", NewMsg_au8)`.
I'm using CodeBlocks 17.12 editor.

I tried hard coding one of the input case like, `NewMsg_au8="0123456789ABCDEF";` — that works fine.

```
uint8 * NewMsg_au8;
scanf("%s",NewMsg_au8);//<== 
printf("Your entered message is: %s\n",NewMsg_au8);
return NewMsg_au8;
```

Comment: Reading into an uninitialized pointer ? Undefined behavior. Reading into a literal string ? Undefined behavior.

Comment: The difference isn't as great as you'd like.  See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/) for why you shouldn't use `gets()`.  However, not placing a size such as `"%31s"` in the `scanf()` leaves you vulnerable to overflows.  In the code, you've not shown where you allocate memory for `NewMsg_au8` to point at — that's another bug. Unlike `gets()`, the `scanf()` will skip leading white space (including newlines) and after it finds one or more other characters, it will stop at the next white space.

Comment: There is no `gets()` here.  Unclear what the real question is.

Comment: The main difference is that `scanf` exists

Comment: *"I declared a character pointer, and used it for to scan a string in runtime; "* - no, you used it to invoke undefined behavior. Scanning a string with `scanf` requires viable memory on which to store the string, and you've delivered none.

Comment: See also [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

`gets(s)` and `scanf("%s", s)` are both unsafe and potentially incorrect because:

- with those calls as shown, there is no way for either function to determine the maximum number of characters to store into the array pointed to by `s`, hence overlong input will cause a buffer overrun leading to undefined behavior.
- in your case, it is even worse as `s` is an uninitialized pointer, so both functions would try a store data into a random address in memory causing undefined behavior in all cases.

`gets()` cannot be used safely and has been deprecated in and then removed from the C Standard.

However, `scanf()` can be given a limit with a numeric value between `%` and `s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read_string(void) {
    char buf[100];
    if (scanf("%99s", buf) == 1) {
        printf("Your entered message is: %s\n", buf);
        return strdup(buf);  /* return an allocated copy of the input string */
    } else {
        /* no input, probably at end of file */
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Note how only 99 characters can be stored into the array `buf` to allow for the null byte terminator that marks the end of a C string. The `%99s` conversion specification lets `scanf()` store at most 100 bytes into `buf`, **including** the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: You might comment that `gets()` — or a replacement like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` — reads a whole line regardless of spaces within the line, whereas the `%s` format skips leading white space, including newlines, and then reads a sequence of other characters up to the next white space character — possibly reading many lines containing only white space, but not reading a whole line if there are spaces between 'words'.

Answer (score 1):

That is a typical beginners error. You do not save data in pointers (with gets() or scanf()) but in buffers.

Therefore, you have 2 solutions:

1. **Use an array big** enough to hold the data. You have to decide yourself what "big enough" means, according to the details of your application.
2. **Use a pointer, and then allocate memory with malloc()** - the size, again, you have to decide it. Do not forget to deallocate the memory when you no longer need it.

---

> I tried hard coding one of the input case like, **NewMsg_au8="0123456789ABCDEF"**; — that works fine.

That is normal, because in that case the compiler automatically allocates enough memory to hold the string.

---

Please always remember when working with strings: you always need to allocate **an extra byte** for the **terminating null character** - the mark of the end of the string. Otherwise, you will need to ask questions again :)